# How to access the item being data bound during ItemDataBound?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to get at the item that is being data bound, during the ItemDataBound event of an asp:repeater.

I tried the following (which was an unaccepted answer in a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284420/datagridview-bindinghow-to-color-line-depending-of-the-object-binded#284470)):

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Object dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
    ...
}
```

but `e.Item.DataItem` is null.

How can I access the item being data bound during the event called ItemDataBound. I assume the event ItemDataBound happens when an item is being data bound.

I want to get at the object so I can take steps to control how it is displayed, in addition the object may have additional helpful properties to let me enrich how it is displayed.

### Answer

[Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344047/aspnet-how-to-access-the-item-being-data-bound-during-itemdatabound#344073) had the right answer. The answer is that `e.Item.Data` is only valid when `e.Item.ItemType` is (Item, AlternatingItem). Other times it is not valid. In my case, I was receiving ItemDataBound events during header (or footer) rows, where there is no DataItem:

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   // if the data bound item is an item or alternating item (not the header etc)
   if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && 
         e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      return;
   }

   Object dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I believe the event is fired *after* the item is databound. I think I used to access data in the PreRender event. Would need to check some old code though

Comment: I personally perfer to do it the way that the answer was done, as it is easier to understand than a randome return to exit especially on a void method like ItemDataBound.  My just opinion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right off the bat I would have to guess you need this:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    //Put stuff here
}
```

After all, the item itself could be representing a header or footer row.

Comment: Yes, this is needed on a repeater

Comment: Yeah I had actually edited this a couple time because in testing it didn't fail without the check so having little experience with repeaters made me think they didn't.  Of course I kind of didn't actually add a Header to test... Brilliant I am.

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to add that I did accomplished this by doing the following:

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
      //determine if the row type is an Item
      if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
      {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        if (row["RowName"].ToString() == "value")
        {
          //INSERT CODE HERE
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This was more helpful for me because it has an example of how to retrieve a specific column's information based on the name.

Answer (score 3):

For repeater

```
if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType...
```

Can be modified to:

```
if (e.Item.DataItem != null) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***dynamic***

```
 dynamic item = e.Item.DataItem;
 string style = item.Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with an asp:ListView, you can do something like this:

```
    protected void myLV_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        return;

    object dataItem = ((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem;

}
```

(The title of the question doesn't mention an asp:repeater.. so I thought it might be helpful to post the code for an asp:listview)

Comment: Although the title doesn't, the first line of the question does; but StackOverflow thanks you for additional helpful material.

Answer (score 0):

For a repeater with a custom template binding; you can use the following template. I used this to create a table which breaks down each data item into two rows for print view.

```
Repeater1.HeaderTemplate = new PrintTemplate(ListItemType.Header);
Repeater1.ItemTemplate = new PrintTemplate(ListItemType.Item);
Repeater1.AlternatingItemTemplate = new  PrintTemplate(ListItemType.AlternatingItem);
Repeater1.FooterTemplate = new PrintTemplate(ListItemType.Footer);

 public class PrintTemplate : ITemplate
{
    ListItemType templateType;

  public PrintTemplate(ListItemType type)
  {
     templateType = type;

  }
  public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
  {       
     Literal lc = new Literal();

     switch(templateType)
     {
        case ListItemType.Header:
           lc.Text = "<TABLE>";
           container.Controls.Add(lc);
           break;
        case ListItemType.Item:
        case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
           //lc.Text = "<TR><TD>";
           lc.DataBinding += new EventHandler(TemplateControl_DataBinding);
           container.Controls.Add(lc);
           break;
        case ListItemType.Footer:
           lc.Text = "</TABLE>";
           container.Controls.Add(lc);
           break;
     }
  }

    private void TemplateControl_DataBinding(object sender,
    System.EventArgs e)
          {

              Literal lc;
              lc = (Literal)sender;
              RepeaterItem container = (RepeaterItem)lc.NamingContainer;
              ListItemType itmType = container.ItemType;

              //construct the repeater row using a custom function that switches on item type; HEADER vs ITEM vs ALTERNATINGITEM
              lc.Text += GetPopulatedRepeaterRow(dataInterface, container.DataItem, container.ItemType); 
              ...
```