# How can I access the parent datasource in data expression syntax in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, databound-controls, nested-controls

I have a Repeater inside the TemplateField for a GridView. GridView is bound to datasource1 and the repeater to datasource2. How can i access datasource1 from the ItemTemplate of repeater in data binding syntax (<%# %>) of repeater itemtemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491537/nested-repeaters-and-sqldatasource-parameters). That question was relevant to Repeaters but you get the idea. The GridView exposes the `RowDataBound` event which you can handle in the same way.

Of course, I don't believe there is a way to access it via the declarative Databinding syntax.