# how to pass an ID from parent ListView to a child Repeater Inside the parent ListView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a listview "CategoriesList" and i have a repeater "NewsRepeater" inside the listview "CategoriesList"

```
<asp:ListView ID="CategoriesList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CatID" DataSourceID="CategoriesListODS"
    EnableModelValidation="True">    
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No data was returned.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>    
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="head-Kuwait-University-news">
            <h2>
                <%# Eval("CatTitleAr")%>
            </h2>
            <asp:Literal ID="CatIDLtl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("CatID")%>' />
        </div>
        <!--End head Kuwait-University-newst-->
        <asp:Repeater ID="NewsRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="NewsRepeaterODS">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="content-Kuwait-University-news">
                    <div class="photo-Kuwait-University-news">
                        <a href="Items.aspx?ItemID=<%# Eval("ItemID")%>">
                            <img src="admin/ImageUpload/Items/<%# Eval("PictureID") %>.jpg" alt="" style="max-height: 141px;
                                max-width: 152px" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--End photo-Kuwait-University-news-->
                    <div class="title-Kuwait-University-news">
                        <p>
                            <%# Eval("ItemTitleAr")%>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--End title-Kuwait-University-news-->
                    <div class="News-Kuwait-University-news">
                        <p>
                            <%# Eval("SDescriptionAr")%>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--End news-Kuwait-University-news-->
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                    <div class="more-Kuwait-University-news">
                        <a href='Item.aspx?ItemID=<%# Eval("ItemID")%>'>
                            <img src="images/more.jpg" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--End more-Kuwait-University-news-->
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Endcontent-Kuwait-University-news-->
                <!--End category-->
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="NewsRepeaterODS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}"
            SelectMethod="Read" TypeName="Items">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="3.5" Name="ActionCode" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="CatID" Type="Int64" DefaultValue='<%# Eval("CatID")%>' />
                <%--<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CategoriesList" Name="CatID" PropertyName="UniqueID" Type="Int64" />--%>
                <asp:Parameter  Name="ItemsID" Type="Int64" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Searchtext" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <!--End category-->
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </ul>
        <div style="">
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                        ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                    <asp:NumericPagerField />
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                        ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>    
</asp:ListView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CategoriesListODS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}"
    SelectMethod="Read" TypeName="Categories">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="3" Name="ActionCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CatID" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Searchtext" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

how to pass the catID from the listview and make it as SelectParameters in ObjectDataSource "NewsRepeaterODS"?

thanks

Comment: Did you saw this question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491537/nested-repeaters-and-sqldatasource-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Sub CategoriesList_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles CategoriesList.ItemDataBound
    ' Find the Inner DataSource control in this Row.
    Dim NewsRepeaterODS As ObjectDataSource = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("NewsRepeaterODS"), ObjectDataSource)

    ' Set the SelectParameter for this DataSource control
    ' by re-evaluating the field that is to be passed.
    Dim CatIDLtl As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("CatIDLtl")
    NewsRepeaterODS.SelectParameters("CatID").DefaultValue = CatIDLtl.Text
End Sub
```