# Shortcut for (e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

When using a DataGrid in ASP.Net is there really no shortcut method for

```
(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```

Basically, "item is an item not a header, footer, separator".

I haven't been able to find one, but I figured I'd put it up to StackOverflow to see if I'm missing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own Extension Method for this:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public static class UiControlsHelper
{
    public static bool IsItem(this DataGridItem item)
    {
        return item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
e.Item.IsItem();
```

Here's the same for the GridView:

```
public static bool IsDataRow(this GridViewRow row)
{
    return row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow;
}
```

Comment: This is what I currently have and so far has proven workable. I was looking for something simpler.

Comment: I don't think you can get simpler than that. You just have to ask e.Item.IsItem() in your if, where you had that long screamer before...

Answer (score 3):

[Sagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144933/sagi) added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344047/asp-net-how-to-access-the-item-being-data-bound-during-itemdatabound/1181696#1181696) to one one [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344047/asp-net-how-to-access-the-item-being-data-bound-during-itemdatabound)s.

> You can replace:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType...
```

> with

```
if (e.Item.DataItem != null) ...
```

His answer, not mine. i've not tested it. i don't know if it's:

- valid
- documented
- supported
- subject to change in future versions of .NET framework

There very well may be a situation where the DataItem is assigned, but it's not a valid item.

Answer (score 2):

Not a short cut, but encapsulate that into a function, and your code will be much more readable.